# What is the best practice for KV object in java?

Tags: java

What is the best practice for creating a single key value object in java?
I know there is: Object, Pair, Map.Entry , KeyValue.
For a simple KV use such as  {"name":"coolName"} what should i use?

Comment: What do you mean by single key value object?

Comment: What are your requirements? How are you planning to use the data?

Comment: `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value)`.

Comment: `Collections.singletonMap`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most standard way to represent a key-value pair is with [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html):

> A map entry (key-value pair).

This is better than the others you suggest because:

- `Object`: has no notion of it having any meaningful structure
- `Pair`: better, but does not semantically convey that the first thing is a key and the second is a value.
- `KeyValue`: don't know what this is, but I don't think it's part of the standard SDK.

`Map.Entry` is in `java.util`, so it's available everywhere.

You can create an instance using:

```
new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value)
```

As pointed out by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8266738/michael), Java 9 adds a [helper method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)):

```
Map.entry(key, value)
```

Comment: And starting with Java 9 you can simply use the static factory method `Map.entry("name", "coolName")`. :)

Comment: @Michael yes; but if you're not on Java 10 yet, you could define that method yourself as a trivial helper.

Comment: True. Actually, it has been introduced with Java 9, not 10.

Comment: what about using Collections.singletonMap?

Comment: @Tomer `Collections.singletonMap` returns a `Map`, which represents zero or more key-value pairs; it is only at runtime that you can discover that there is exactly one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pair<K,V>` (implementation of `Map.Entry<K,V>` from commons-lang3) and the relevant method in Java 11: [Map.entry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)).